# Exponential Decay Curve fit on Python. Error: Optimizewarning

Tags: python, exponential

I am trying to make a curvefit for my data. I am using the exponential function as I need tau (time constant) for further analysis. I am new to Python and trying the scipy curvefit function for the first time. However, I just obtain a straight line and the code gives `OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated warnings.warn`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


x = np. array( [ 246, 248, 250, 252, 254,256, 258, 260, 262, 264, 266, 268, 270, 272, 274, 276, 278, 280, 282,284])
y = np.array( [ 6.38954156, 6.32462716 ,6.21843495,5.96263661, 5.66970206, 5.37948873, 5.06358679 ,4.83386528 ,4.64262524, 4.5091623,  4.38658648, 4.46124359, 4.52878251, 4.56084217 ,4.47660524,4.5323503,  4.46626654, 4.58289275, 4.42962004, 4.29622583])

def curvefit( x, a, invtau,c):
      return a * np.exp(-x*invtau)+c
popt, pcov = curve_fit( curvefit, x, y)   #Curvefit
a, invtau, c = popt         #summarize the parameter values
x_new = np.arange(min(x), max(x),1)
y_new = curvefit (x_new, a, invtau, c)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot (x_new, y_new, '--', label='fit')
plt.legend (loc='upper right')
```

I saw that the output of `y_new` is same for all the rows because of which it gives a straight line.

Question: How to estimate the parameters to make a curvefit for my data?

[This is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y58DV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set some good starting values for your fit parameters. The default will be 1 for all parameters (`a`, `invtau` and `c`), but especially `a` and `invtau` will be far from 1. Then, the optimizer algorithm will fail to find a good minimum.

I tried with

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit( curvefit, x, y, p0=[1, 1/250, 4])   #Curvefit
```

which yields a decent fit, and values for `a`, `invtau` and `c` of `4335942530.560109`, `0.0865584128551326` and `4.238729282912057`, respectively.

(Note that I had the starting value for `a` as `1`, which is still far away from its actual value. But having `invtau` closer to its actual value, lets the algorithm then also find a good fit for `a`. It is overall still better to provide more accurate starting values for *all* parameters, and since you're modeling your data, you probably know what to expect for those values, and use that as a starting point.)

Comment: This works for one sample data but if I need to repeat the model for multiple y data vs x (seconds), it is hard to get a good fit with the same default `po` values. How can I set the guessing of the parameters variable for different columns?

Comment: @Ankita You can probably calculate a guess from your model and the data, without being precise. I noticed there was an offset of about 4 to 5, so I set `c` to 4. I also noticed that the `x` values around the leveling off area were around 250, so hence 1/250 for `invtau` (that assumes a decay of 1 in `y` for a step in `x`, roughly). And so on. Use your model and data to calculate an initial estimate, then refine it with a fitting routine.